# How can I set a RAM limit for a specific user in Linux?

Tags: linux, memory, restrictions

How can I set a RAM limit for a specific user? I have tried editing the `/etc/security/limits.conf` file, and the RAM limits there, but I still see a users process exceeding the limit set.

I know that the limits are specified in kb, so I'm not using an incorrect number.

For instance, I am trying to set it so that a user can't use more than 2,048mb (or 2,097,152kb) of memory, and their program will use like 2500mb.

Is there any way that I can accomplish this without virtual machines? I am also trying to stay away from running virtual machines as an option.

Here's my [`/etc/sysconfig/limits.conf`](http://privatepaste.com/65650d1e29).

Also, the RSS limit is ignored since the kernel version I'm running is 2.6.18

Comment: Q: Is there any way that I can accomplish this without virtual machines?  A: I don't think so :)

Comment: can you post your /etc/security/limits.conf file?

Comment: I edited it with a pastebin link to the file.

Answer (score 1):

The controls related to memory are enforced via per process resource limits.  The process limits related to memory have been partly broken for a long time under Linux.  Example:

```
$ (ulimit -m 1; emacs)
```

If Emacs starts up, clearly the RSS resource limit is not being enforced.  The limits that I have seen work are the data segment and stack limits.

```
$ (ulimit -d 1; emacs)
emacs: Memory exhausted--use M-x save-some-buffers RET
$ (ulimit -s 1; emacs)
$
```

So use only the "data" and "stack" memory limits, since these seem to be enforced.

Answer (score -1):

To limit the available resources for a set of processes, for users or for groups, you can use `cgroups`:
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v1/cgroups.txt

Comment: link-only answers are not helpful.